# Content hidden behind fixed show/hide div above navbar-fixed-top on vertical scroll

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

When clicking a link/button, I have a banner that will show above the navbar-fixed-top navbar and both will push the page content down and remain fixed on vertical scroll.  The problem I am having is once the page is **scrolled down and back up to the top** again, part of the top of the page content is hidden behind the navbar and visible banner. I don't want that to happen but nothing I have tried is working.  I appreciate the help!

```
<div class="page">    
      <div class="container-fluid banner">
      <h1>Random gibberish</h1>
      <h3>plenty uneasy do.</h3>
      <p>Friendship so considered . </p>
      <p>Moment led family ...</p>
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse w100">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Global Topnav</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="container content">
      <h2>Betrayed cheerful declared end...</h2>        
      <p>Prepared is me marianne pleasure ...</p>        
      <p>Lose john poor ...</p>
      <div class="btn btn-warning btn-lg show-banner">
         Show banner
      </div>
    </div>
```

[This FIDDLE will show it better](https://jsfiddle.net/kovqh4qk/5/)

Comment: Not so much clear what exactly you want. For me it seems working fine.

Comment: The page content starting with the `<h2>Betrayed cheerful declared end...</h2><p>Prepared is me marianne pleasure ...</p>`  at the top is being covered up by the navbar and the banner when you scroll back to the top after scrolling down.  I don't want that to happen.  I dont want any portion of the content to be covered when you scroll back to the top.

Comment: problem is with script, when scroll it will add class but not removing class when we move to top. you need to add position.top + 50 in if condition. When we move down top position will be 0. so when we move back it cant remove class.

Comment: This means you have to track the scroll event and scroll up the header content div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that when you scroll up again the class fixed is not removed from the page and that's because you are using `if (winPosition >= position.top)` in your JQuery code when you should use `if (winPosition > position.top)` instead.

[**See jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/codename0/kovqh4qk/6/)